# Same stylesheet being bundled into different bundles and loaded multiple times

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, less, antd

I'm building a React/Antd project with less stylesheets.

While running on webpack development server everything seems fine but when I build the project, the same stylesheet seemed to be loaded when I visit different pages.

For example, I have styled Card components in Page 1 and Page 2.
When I visit Page 1, the Card component is correctly styled with the correct declaration order:

```
.my-custom-card {
  margin: 10px;
}

.ant-card {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Then when I visit page 2 and go back to page 1, the same ant-card stylesheet is loaded. The declaration order now becomes:

```
.ant-card {
  margin: 0;
}

.my-custom-card {
  margin: 10px;
}

.ant-card {
  margin: 0;
}
```

and the margin declared with my custom class is overwritten by the newly loaded ant-card stylesheet.

To clarify, the only stylesheet that contains .ant-card comes from the antd package. This stylesheet has been loaded from the same bundle for twice.

This does not happen on webpack-dev-server, only when I build the project, so I'm leaning towards potential problems during the build.

Comment: For anybody that stumbled into this problem, what I didn't do was to properly optimize the webpack SplitChunksPlugin. Default settings should do the trick. 
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Webpack dev server serves the raw files and assets locally. It wont use the bundled files. When the bundles are created, if there are conflicting styles, it would be good to lock your css styles with a container css class.

```
  .page1-container {
    .ant-card {
          margin: 10px; 
          }
       }
   }
  .page2-container {
    .ant-card {
         margin: 20px;
         }
     }     
   }
```

Comment: Don't know if this information would help but - the same stylesheet is loaded multiple times from the same bundle.